# Create User-Specific Redirect After Login in django

Tags: django, django-registration

I have three types of people in my Django application Admin, Staff and Parent . how can I set up log-in for them as they will have different views after logging in using django registration?
my code so far is this :
in settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/app/login_redirect'
LOGIN_URL = '/app/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/app/accounts/logout/'
```

and in views.py:

```
def login_redirect(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and not request.user.is_superuser:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dashboard"))
    elif request.user.is_superuser:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dashboard"))
```

I want to identify the which user is logged in ? I mean is it a staff user or a parent user or a admin? 
model.py

```
class Student(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User",blank=True,null=True,related_name="user_%(class)s_objects")
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    admission_number = models.CharField(max_length=128,null=True,blank=True)
    transportation_needs = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=TRANSPORTATION_NEEDS,blank=True,null=True) 
    extended_care_need = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=EXTENDED_CARE_NEED,blank=True,null=True) 
    nationality = CountryField (blank_label='------( select Your Country)-------',max_length=128,blank=True,null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    permanent_address = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True,null=True)
    address_for_communication = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True,null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=GENDER_CHOICE)
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? show some code or at least elaborate the scenario bit more in detail...

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: how does the parent user is distinguished, is there a field `is_parent`??

Comment: no ..
 
request.user is the User object from django auth user model. So there is no field called is_parent()

Comment: could you show the models then,

Comment: You should create a secondary user-profile which would contain some additional detail about user which is not there in default User model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way this can be achieved is by adding groups. Create group objects(with names as "partent", "student", "teacher") and add respective users to that group. By this way you dont have to override/change auth.User model.

```
 def login_redirect(request):
     if request.user.is_authenticated():
         user_groups = request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)    
         if request.user.is_superuser:
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin"))
         elif "parent" in user_groups:
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("parent_dashboard"))
         elif "student" in user_groups:
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("student_dashboard"))
```

Hope this helps.